# Type mismatch when using Scala Trait in Play?

Tags: scala, playframework

Using the Play! Framework 1.2.4. I've got a nifty trait that checks an API key and HTTPS, but if I want to access the account associated with that key and reference it in my controller, it throws a `type mismatch; found : java.lang.Object required: Long`

So here's my API controller (incomplete):

```
object API extends Controller with Squeryl with SecureAPI {

  import views.API._

  def job(param:String) = {


    val Job = models.Job
    param match {
      case "new"    => Job.createFromParams(params,thisAccount) //thisAccount comes from the trait
      case "update" =>
      case "get"    =>
      case "list"   =>
    }
  }

}
```

and the secure trait:

```
trait SecureAPI {
  self:Controller =>

  @Before
  def checkSecurity(key:String) = {
      if(!self.request.secure.booleanValue) {
          Redirect("https://" + request.host + request.url);
      } else {
          models.Account.getByKey(key) match {
            case Some(account)  =>  {
              renderArgs += "account" -> account.id
              Continue
            }
            case _  =>  Forbidden("Key is not authorized.")
          }
      }
  }

  def thisAccount = renderArgs("account").get
}
```

How would I properly access `thisAccount`? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is simply that `renderArgs` is only declared to return an `Object` from its `get` call (which is fair enough because it could be just about anything).

Consequently the inferred type of your `thisAccount` method will be `() => Object`.

You'll need to cast the returned type into a Long, something like (though perhaps with some error-checking):

```
def thisAccount = renderArgs("account").get.asInstanceOf[Long]
```

Comment: And that compiles nicely! Still learning and I didn't think about using asInstanceOf for that. Very helpful thank you

Comment: @DeLonge It's a good thing not to think of `asInstanceOf`! :-) You can also do pattern matching, which is safer.

Comment: @Daniel I agree, that's the sort of error-checking that I was alluding to - though its not obvious what sort of behaviour is required in the error case (this is app-specific).  In retrospect perhaps it is detrimental to give answers that are short, convenient, and wrong.

Comment: So instead of using `asInstanceOf` on the trait, I can apply pattern matching in the controller? Say like... `val accountId = thisAccount match {case Some(Long)...`? It's a lot of matching, any shorthand?